# Use interior door as shed door but under cover

Tags: doors, roof, shed, porch, cover

I have a shed with a front porch and roof cover (5x8 feet). I plan to put an interior door at the shed wall but under this cover area. Is it OK? This won't be soaking wet. It will be slightly wet if rain with strong wind. I am guessing an interior door hollow core can stand lightly wet once in awhile and cold/hot temperature for at least few years. Let me know if you have a different take?!

Comment: This comes down to opinion. What's your tolerance for aesthetic degradation? Chances are you'll see minor swelling after the first wet event, slight delamination after the second, and so on. If "a few years" is all you're after, go for it. Just don't expect more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interior doors definitely do not work. I tried them with 3/8 exterior plywood covering the outer surface of the doors and they still fell apart in a few years.

Comment: Even if it's under cover like a porch? I think couple years is acceptable for me.

Comment: The doors were just below a 12 " overhang. They probably lasted 5 years.

Comment: Since I asked this question, the door has been OK throughout the summer and winter. It didn't get wet at all. I can post pictures if interested.

Comment: Post them in 5 years. I am in a humid environment, East TX.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a hollow core, then no, it won't be okay.
A solid core or panel door of some kind will be okay for a while, but you'll get the longest life out of an exterior grade door.